# Flask route query parameter

Tags: python, rest, flask, routes, werkzeug

Say I have two routes set up with Flask:

```
app.add_url_rule('/example', view_func = example.Index.as_view('example'))
app.add_url_rule('/example/<string:example_key>', view_func = example.Show.as_view('example'), methods=['GET'])
```

This routes /example to example.Index and /example/1 to example.Show.

When I go to /example?parameter=miau however it routes to example.Show instead of example.Index.

Why does this happen and how should I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out, mind the "example.Index.as_view('example')", it should be:

```
app.add_url_rule('/example', view_func = example.Index.as_view('example_index'))
app.add_url_rule('/example/<string:example_key>', view_func = example.Show.as_view('example_show'), methods=['GET'])
```

Comment: Why this happened: the first parameter to `as_view` is the name of the generated view function, which is the default “endpoint”. Flask maps URL rules to endpoints, and then endpoints to view functions. In the first code sample both views had the same name so both rules had the same endpoint. The same view function (the latter) was used in both cases.